# Java XMLStreamReader.getText() chokes on XML encoded characters?

Tags: java, xml, parsing, iso-8859-1, xmlstreamreader

I am trying to parse a giant (> 1GB) xml file using Java's XMLStreamReader.  I use the getText() method to pull the contents of a node.  The xml file I have is encoded as ISO-8859-1, and some characters have special encoding, for example `&` is encoded as `&amp;` in the file.

So if the file contains, for example:

```
<person>Jack</person>
<person>Jill</person>
<persons>Jack &amp; Jill</persons>
```

And I try to get the contents of each node using getText(), the 3rd node only returns `Jack`.  Any time a `&xxx;` character is encountered, no characters after it (in the same node) are parsed or returned.

Where is the problem?  Is the xml file encoded correctly?  Am I using the Java parser correctly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that the problem is that the parser has split the contents of the 3rd persons elements into multiple processing events.  (This behaviour of `next()` is [documented](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/stream/XMLStreamReader.html#next%28%29).)  Calling `getText()` is only giving you the text for the current event.

Try using [`getElementText()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/stream/XMLStreamReader.html#getElementText%28%29) instead.

Comment: Yes, that seems to be the root of the problem, thanks very much!